# Delete records not present in join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Imagine two tables (A and B):

```
A        B
1        2
2        3 
6        5 
4        7
9        11
         13
         23
         9
```

Now I want to delete records from A that are not present in B, e.g deleting 1, 6 and 4 from A.

My initial idea is that you could 'negate' the results of a join.

Comment: Was this homework, by the way? It kind of looks like homework but it's a little late since you got complete answers :)

Comment: It is not. It is for use in a hobby project. Abstractions were made for simplicity.

Comment: Fair enough! We often ask so we don't quickly solve people's assignments for them. Cheers.

Comment: Nooo problem, I could see how unknowingly solving people's homework could be a pain. And thanks again for your valuable input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id)
```

I've assumed that those columns are named `id`.

Comment: had to change to DELETE FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id)

Comment: I edited the `ON` to be a `WHERE` as I think it should be (otherwise its not valid syntactically)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the `NOT EXISTS` answer:

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM b);
```

Again, assuming the column is named `id`.

Comment: It turns out I keep using your suggestion for different purposes, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can find the records that are unmatched by looking for a NULL value on one side of an outer join, then delete those:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE id IN
   (
   SELECT A.id
   FROM A
   LEFT JOIN B
   ON A.id = B.id
   WHERE B.id IS NULL  -- This means we only return unmatched A records
   )
```

The main reason I like this is that you can run the `SELECT` part of the statement beforehand so that you can check your work. Otherwise the other answers look much cleaner.

Comment: Good call on running a SELECT before a DELETE. That definitely helps avoiding a potential headache.

Comment: so all method here about multi select query, i was thinking there should be any join like solution